# Creating Single file Runnable Jars in Scala with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala

Can anyone tell me how I can create a runnable JAR file from a Scala program using Eclipse and Scala 2.9.x ?

A quick Google brings up results like this ..

http://garyboone.com/2009/06/creating-single-file-runnable-jars-in-scala-and-eclipse/

Which uses a Java class to call the Scala main however it doesn't seem to work with Scala 2.9.

Thanks for your time.

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, by chance, you're using sbt to build then you can use the [assembly-sbt](https://github.com/codahale/assembly-sbt) plugin. We use this at Yammer to build fat JARs of our infrastructure services. We're (gradually) switching over to use maven and the [shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). I believe shade does a slightly more intelligent job of merging JARs than assembly-sbt does. However, we've had great success so far with assembly-sbt.

Comment: My thanks to everyone who replied. I got three good answers and its a pity I can only select one. I have picked this one for its mention of the Shade plugin which I have tried and it all seems to work well.

Answer (score 13):

In Scala 2.9.1, you can simply create a .java file like this to be able to make use of Eclipse's Create Runnable JAR functionality:

```
public class ScalaRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. You need to select this class and Run as Java Application to create the Launch Configuration before exporting the JAR

Answer (score 1):

Not Eclipse specific, but I would use sbt with the Proguard plugin: https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-proguard-plugin

This lets you setup a reusable build without depending on Eclipse or similar IDEs.

Answer (score 1):

Proguard is a great tool to create an executable jar -- if you're not using sbt (if so, use the sbt-proguard-plugin other folks are advising) a standard way to build the executable jar from within eclipse would be to build an ant build file, and then reference that ant build from within eclipse.

Almost all android developers who use scala use proguard, and you'll find lots of documentation from them about this.

Here's proguard documentation about creating an ant task:
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/ant.html

And step 4 from this page about android development from scala IDE wiki has the specific steps for adding the ant build file to eclipse.

http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/scala-ide/Developing_for_Android